# Spring Tool Suite 4 auto closes on certain key press

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, sts, spring-tools-4

I am on Mac OS Ventura and using STS installed from binary `spring-tool-suite-4-4.16.1.RELEASE-e4.25.0-macosx.cocoa.x86_64.dmg`. I see an issue when editing the `pom.xml` file. Whenever I try to comment out a dependency by typing in `<!`, STS abruptly closes. Also typing `<!` in any other file doesn't close the application, it happens only on XML files.

I didn't notice this behavior when using the same binary on Mac OS BigSur.

Logs

```
!SESSION 2022-11-10 22:51:18.936 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.16.1.202210240748
java.version=17.0.4.1
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 -keyring /Users/abcdef/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 -keyring /Users/abcdef/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2022-11-10 22:51:20.327
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2022-11-10 22:51:22.392
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2022-11-10 22:51:22.392
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for COMMAND+SHIFT+T:
Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type"),
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),
        WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler("org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace"),
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2022-11-10 22:51:22.392
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+COMMAND+R:
Binding(ALT+COMMAND+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename,Rename,
        Rename the selected item,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.file,File,null,true),
        WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler("org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename"),
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,cocoa,system)
Binding(ALT+COMMAND+R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element"),
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,cocoa,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2022-11-10 22:51:30.049
!MESSAGE The POM for com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2022-11-10 22:51:31.994
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because "links" is null
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.documentLink.LSPDocumentLinkPresentationReconcilingStrategy.underline(LSPDocumentLinkPresentationReconcilingStrategy.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.documentLink.LSPDocumentLinkPresentationReconcilingStrategy.lambda$5(LSPDocumentLinkPresentationReconcilingStrategy.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4318)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3941)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

Comment: Seems like it's been reported via https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/888 .

Comment: @nitind I have only reported that.